# How to set Content-Encoding with gzip

Tags: http, http-headers, gzip

I am compressing html files with gzip.
The browser (FF 3.0.10) does not decompress or display index.html.gz (pre-compressed on the server) when I request index.html

Where can I confirm the zipped header "content-encoding" and the browsers "Accept-Encoding"?
(I am using the zlib API in C for zipping)

Thanks.

Comment: How is the delivery of your .gz implemented?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859155/how-can-i-compress-a-char-array-into-a-compressed-html-page-using-zlib

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if the browser sends

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

you can compress the **content** of your http response, not the file on the server's file system. Then in your HTTP response you must set these headers:

```
Content-Length: totalBytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: Is the accepted answer wrong here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858830/file-extention-of-zlib-zipped-html-page

Comment: isn't the file the content of the response anyway?

Answer (score 6):

(You should also set Vary: Accept-Encoding in the response, technically, to make it clear to caches that the response will be different depending on this request header.)