# Programmatically putting .html file into ZIP scrambles text

Tags: java, html, servlets, utf-8, zip

Using java, I take a string that represents some HTML:

```
String webPage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:csi='http://www.massimocorner.com/libraries/csi/' lang='de'>" +
                        "<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/> ..... </html>
```

and put it into a zip file like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
ZipStreamOutput output = new ZipStreamOutput( byteArrayOutputStream );
OutputStream os = output.addStream(Integer.toString(i) +".html");
os.write(webPage.getBytes()); 
os.flush();
output.finish(); 
byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Then I serve the ZIP file from my servelet like this:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType( "application/zip"); 
response.setContentLength( data.length ); 
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="  + "filename.zip"); 
response.getOutputStream().write( data );
```

When I extract the ZIP file and open the HTML file in my browser it is not rendering in UTF-8 even though the HTML  indicates that it should.

If I just serve the HTML file without compressing it it renders normally.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you use to generate the HTML? Specifically, what type of object is `webPage`?

Comment: A string. String webPage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:csi='http://www.massimocorner.com/libraries/csi/' lang='de'>.... etc.

Comment: Are you sure the string is UTF8? .NET strings are UTF16 (UCS2)

Comment: You're right Cole. Changing .getBytes());  to .getBytes("UTF8"));  fixed the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send the compressed version of the HTML and have the browser render the HTML, then you want to set the Content-Encoding header to "gzip" and the Content-Type header to "text/html". Compress the page with GZIPOutputStream instead of ZIPOutputStream. Check the "Accept" request header to make sure the browser supports this kind of compression.

See [How to set Content-Encoding with gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864448/how-to-set-content-encoding-with-gzip)

You can also do this with a Servlet filter:
http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html